# Conversion of PNG image to base64 in Windows phone7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to convert a PNG image found in a path to base64 for a html page in Windows phone7.1.How can it be done?

```
        Stream imgStream;
        imgStream =   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("NewUIChanges.Htmlfile.round1.png");
        byte[] data = new byte[(int)imgStream.Length];
        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < data.Length)
        {
            int bytesRead = imgStream.Read(data, offset, data.Length - offset);
            if (bytesRead <= 0)
            {
                throw new EndOfStreamException("Stream wasn't as long as it claimed");
            }
            offset += bytesRead;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it's a PNG image is actually irrelevant - all you need to know is that you've got some *bytes* that you need to convert into base64.

Read the data from a stream into a byte array, and then use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx). Reading a byte array from a stream can be slightly fiddly, depending on whether the stream advertises its length or not. If it does, you can use:

```
byte[] data = new byte[(int) stream.Length];
int offset = 0;
while (offset < data.Length)
{
    int bytesRead = stream.Read(data, offset, data.Length - offset);
    if (bytesRead <= 0)
    {
        throw new EndOfStreamException("Stream wasn't as long as it claimed");
    }
    offset += bytesRead;
}
```

If it doesn't, the simplest approach is probably to copy it to a `MemoryStream`:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return ms.ToByteArray();
}
```

So once you've used *either* of those bits of code (or anything else suitable) to get a byte array, just use `Convert.ToBase64String` and you're away.

There are probably streaming solutions which will avoid ever having the whole byte array in memory - e.g. building up a `StringBuilder` of base64 data as it goes - but they would be more complicated. Unless you're going to deal with very large files, I'd stick with the above.

Comment: hi jon,How to convert an image in path to stream?

Comment: @yoges1: What sort of path? Do you mean a URL, or a path in local storage? If it's in local storage, you'll need to use the isolated storage API. There are plenty of pages about that on MSDN. (Windows Phone 7 tutorials will generally include it.)

Comment: @yoges1: In that case you'd use `WebClient` or `WebRequest`. (In future, please be clearer to start with - "path" usually refers to a local filename.)

Comment: @yoges1: Not without a more detailed question, no. What do you mean?

Comment: I was not able to convert the image(from local path) in to stream.I updated my code above.

Comment: I thought it *wasn't* a local image? I suspect you may be best off asking a new question, putting *much* more time into explaining exactly what the problem is. Also, you say that it doesn't work - but without saying in what *way* it doesn't work. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I am gettin null exception. imgStream is getting null.

Comment: @yoges1: That suggests that the file *isn't* embedded into your assembly.